# XCharter dilemma: Must I choose between breaking math or pseudocode displays?

Tags: fonts, algorithm2e, xcharter

I'm trying to set up fonts for a document with both math and algorithm blocks. I am using XCharter fonts and the `algorithm2e` package. For some reason, I can't get both typeset right. Here is a MWE to demonstrate my problem.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{XCharter} % needed for math fonts, uncommenting will break fonts in the algorithm environment 
\usepackage[xcharter,bigdelims,slantedGreek,vvarbb,scaled=1.07]{newtxmath} % math, iso 31-compliant(ish)
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XCharter}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    a + b = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \times \alpha' \, \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{l}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \alpha + \upbeta = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\partial \upPi}{\partial \Theta} \times \epsilon' \, \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{\gamma}
\end{equation*}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{this text}
    \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
    initialization\;
    \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
    go to next section\;
    current section becomes this one\;
    }{
    go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
    }
    \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

If don't I use the `XCharter` package, then differentials (using the d) are typeset using Computer Modern.

[image: Differentials are typeset using Computer Modern]

If I do use it, differentials are typeset properly, but the algorithm block is badly rendered.

[image: Wrongly rendered algorithm block]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the nonstandard font setup, you need to help:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xcharter,bigdelims,slantedGreek,vvarbb,scaled=1.07]{newtxmath} % math, iso 31-compliant(ish)
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XCharter}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{metalogox}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{XCharter-TLF}{m}{n}%
  \SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{XCharter-TLF}{b}{n}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    a + b = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \times \alpha' \, \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{l}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \alpha + \upbeta = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\partial \upPi}{\partial \Theta} \times \epsilon' \, \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{\gamma}
\end{equation*}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetAlgoLined
    \KwData{this text}
    \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeXe}
    initialization\;
    \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
    go to next section\;
    current section becomes this one\;
    }{
    go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
    }
    \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]